# cant access localhost on my phone

Tags: php, android, localhost

I have an android connected to wifi. I want to access the localhost from my windows pc with my phone because i am creating a mobile web app that i want to access through my localhost in the phone. I tried 192.168.x.x/8080/. I also tried the routers ip with it.  I dont know if i am doing anything wrong. Firewall is off and i followed every instructions i could see on stackoverflow but none of it work for me. I also tried google for answers almost all of it works to install a localhost to my phone none for actually accessing it in my phone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you have apache on Windows machine and you want to access it with a phone? Apache usually runs on port 80 so it's 192.168.x.x:80. What kind of error do you see? 404? 403?

Comment: when i go to 192.168.x.x/8080 i encounter forbidden you dont have permission to access 8080 on the server...when i tried it with :8080 is says like the page does not exist or moved

Comment: If you get a 403, the connection is working. It's the server configuration that makes it respond with 403.

Comment: yeah that is what i thought so also. any suggestions as to what configuration might cause 403? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to try:

- To check what port apache is listening for, go to your apache directory, open the conf sub-directory, and open httpd.conf.  Look for "Listen."  I believe it's 80 by default, but just to be sure, edit it to read:

  `Listen 80`

Or set it to whatever port you want, but 80 is the only one you won't have to explicitly type in your url.

- Open a command prompt on your pc and type ipconfig.  Try the IPv4 address in your Android's browser (mine is 10.0.0.2 and connects to my apache server just fine).

Your problem could obviously be anything, but these are some common solutions.

Comment: ok i tried it again and it worked and i dont know why..tried the same 192.168.x.x.. anyway thanks for all this.. it actually helped

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `10.0.2.2` instead of `192.168.x.x`

[image]

See the [`Android Documentation.`](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: i tried it. still nothing.

Comment: Have you set permissions on your Manifest for accessing internet ?

Comment: OP's not using an emulator but an actual device as far as I understood the question.

Comment: yes i am using an actual device. i want to be able to use localhost so only people who are connected to wifi can access the site.